# Exception when try to create new collation using ICU for .NET

Tags: c#, collation, icu

Try to create new collation using [ICU extension for .NET](https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet):

```
var newCollation = Icu.Collation.Collator.Create("Cyrillic_General_CI_AS");
```

Following exception occures:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   icu.net.dll Additional information: Unable to create a collator using
>   the given localeId. This is likely because the ICU data file was
>   created without collation rules for this locale. You can provide the
>   rules yourself or replace the data dll.

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined collator for *ru-RU-u-co-ks-level2*. You can pass the *FallBackAllowed* parameter so that it falls back to *ru*.

```
Icu.Collation.Collator.Create("ru-RU-u-co-ks-level2", Collator.Fallback.FallbackAllowed)
```

Or do as the exception message says and define your own collation rules.

You can see the predefined collators by looking at the [icu4c source tree](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4c/source/data/coll).

Answer (score 0):

The collation identifier you supply is the form that SQL Server uses but ICU uses a [locale](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale) to identify the collation. Cyrillic General is used by Russian, Bulgarian and many other languages that use Cyrillic script. CI means case insensitive and AS means accent sensitive so I would use locale ru-RU-[u-co-ks-level2](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Setting_Options) to get similar behavior.

Comment: The same error with the expression `Icu.Collation.Collator.Create("ru-RU-u-co-ks-level2")`.